# AirPod features without Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, airpods

I bought a pair of Apple Airpods Pro (2021) used from Ebay that are still linked to their original Apple ID and this cannot be undone.

What features do I lose by being unable to replace the Apple ID? I’m trying to decide whether to return them for a refund or not.

Comment: So far the pairing works fine, and the only feature I know I would not have is the Find My Airpods feature, which would be nice if I lost them.

Comment: If the ebay seller cannot remove the id lock then you should consider that they may be stolen. If you want full functionality then return them. Or if you want them on the cheap then live with how they work now.

Comment: Have you called Apple and asked them to unlink it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out running a 15-second-long reset removes the old Apple ID, so this question is irrelevant.

Steps for the full reset are [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209463).